# Need to match a pattern occurrence only once in a file

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have multiple files with some pattern

```
ABCD  100
ABCD   200
EFGH    500
IJKL      50
EFGH    700
ABCD    800
IJKL    100
```

I want match the occurrence of each (ABCD/EFGH/IJKL) only once sorted based on highest numbers in column 2

```
ABCD   800
EFGH    700
IJKL    100
```

I tried `cat *txt | sort -k 1 |`??

thanks in Advance

My bad, for not being explicit. Apologies for wasting your time.
Below is detailed example. The file has multiple columns. I got the one's needed using awk
and tried this cat *txt |awk '{print $3,$5}' | sort -gr |less. Now I got the strings sorted based on numeral value. Now how do I get the uniq string for the first match.

```
<string>                <numeral>
abcde/efgh/ijkl/mnop    -450.00
dfgh/adas/gfda/adasd    -100.0
abcde/efgh/ijkl/mnop     -100.00
lk/oiojl/ojojl           -0.078
dfgh/adas/gfda/adasd   50.0
lk/oiojl/ojojl       -0.150
O/p needed
abcde/efgh/ijkl/mnop     -450.00
dfgh/adas/gfda/adasd    -100.0
lk/oiojl/ojojl       -0.150
```

Comment: Does number of spaces between two columns matter in result?

Comment: It would be helpful to give exact input and desired output.

Comment: my bad. I thought would be able to decipher from hints :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sort` twice: once to sort on the numbers, a second time to do a *stable* sort on the strings (so that the largest number remains first), removing duplicates to discard duplicate strings with smaller numbers.

```
sort -k2,2nr file.txt | sort -k1,1 -u --stable
```

Comment: Great it worked absolutely as desired and very clean. Finally I used this  cat *txt | awk '{print $3,$5}' | sort -k2 -n | sort -k1,1 -u --stable| less . I was able to get unique string only once with lowest number(-ve). Can you please explain --stable. I could not find its use. Thanks

Comment: Since `sort -u` removes duplicates (by keeping the first one) based only on the given keys, we want to make sure that even though we are sorting the entire list on the first field, we want to make sure that, e.g., "ABCD 800" is not sorted after "ABCD 200". A stable sort guarantees that items that compare equal (and thus could be listed in either order in the output) remain in the same order as they appear in the input. Not all sorting algorithms are stable; heap sort is one such example. The `--stable` option ensures that a stable sort is applied to the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk's associate array and then sort based on column 2:

```
awk '{ if ($2>arr[$1]) arr[$1]=$2} END{for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file \
| sort -k2 -rn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat *txt | perl -ane 'END{print "$_ $r{$_}\n" for sort keys %r} $_<$F[1] and $_=$F[1] for $r{$F[0]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first column is always 4 characters, then (per abasu's suggestion) you can use `uniq -w4`.

`cat *.txt | sort -gr | uniq -w4`

This sorts in reverse order numerically, ('ABCD 800' will precede 'ABCD 100') and only considers the first 4 characters when finding unique rows.

If the first column is not always 4 characters, you can pipe back and forth to `rev`, and use `uniq -f1` to skip the first of the reversed fields.

`cat *.txt | sort -gr | rev | uniq -f1 | rev`

If you want to target a specific word, and get the highest corresponding number, you can use

`cat *.txt | sort -gr | grep 'ABCD' | head -n 1`

Comment: thats not what the OP asked

Comment: still wrong I'm afraid. OP needs `ABCD   800
EFGH    700
IJKL    100` And you got an [UUoCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) heading your way...

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. It works for finding a specific word, like 'ABCD', but to get a distinct list is a different matter.

Comment: @ktm5124, I think uniq will fail because it compares the lines, now `ABCD 100` is different than `ABCD 400`, So probably `uniq -w4` is needed.

Comment: @abasu: right, or you could do `sort -gr | rev | uniq -f1`; but if it's always 4 characters, `uniq -w4` is best.

Comment: seems right :) actually `awk`/`perl` is a fancy tool to do many things, but the `fancyness` actually kills all the fun :) +1 for coming up with such a nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -anE'$h{$F[0]}=$F[1]if!exists$h{$F[0]}or$F[1]>$h{$F[0]}}{say"$_ $h{$_}"for keys%h'
```